# AWS glue crawler parses parquet's timetick weirdly

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-glue

**base**
I download the log with python every day (with cronjob, using ipython).
The download server is CENTOS7, dockerized ubuntu

```
(base) root@:/# uname -a
Linux f5210d345285 3.10.0-957.21.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 5 14:26:44 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

server DateTime is set to utc

**cron Process**
1. Download from athena
2. Make pandas dataframe
3. Get aggregation data from mysql server (onpremise)
4. Join & aggregation
5. Make final dataframe
6. Upload to s3

```py
final_df.to_parquet(temp_filename, compression=None, engine='fastparquet')
FH = open(temp_filename, 'rb')
data_bytes = FH.read()
FH.close()
os.remove(filename)
boto3.session.resource('s3').Object(bucketname, s3pathname).put(Body=data_bytes)
```

7. Work with glue-crawler
8. Get data from athena and use it (like tableau)

**problem**
1. The problem is datetime column.
2. The datetime column name is 'reg_date', and it comes from mariadb column that type is 'datetime'
3. When I display dataframe and operation with it, the 'reg_date' works fine.
4. If I run the next code, it works just right too.

```py
final_df.to_parquet(temp_filename, compression=None, engine='fastparquet')
read_df = pd.read_parquet(temp_filename)
display(read_df)
```

5. And when I check s3 parquet file on the AWS console web browser with s3, it shows no problem. (I click s3 -> bucket -> path -> file -> select source -> preview)

```
    [
    {
        "id": "1251616",
        "press": "8",
        "reg_date": "2019-05-22T14:06:25.000Z", #this line
        "scenario_id": 5072,
        "scheduletype": "1",
        "url": "some url string",
        "user_id": "some id string",
        "writer": "some writer name string",
        "deleted": "0",
        "display": "1",
        "keyword": "some keyword string",
        "modifier": "some modifier string",
        "scenario_reg_date": "2019-05-15 15:04:24",
        "sentence": "some long string..",
        "standby_transmission": "1",
        "subject": "some long string..",
        "scenario_user_id": "some user id string",
        "press_name": "some string",
        "press_url": "some url string",
        "press_host": "some url string",
        "gaid": "some string",
        "article_number": 233235,
        "article_uid": "some string",
        "ga:adsenseadsclicks": 0,
        "ga:adsenseadsviewed": 11,
        "ga:adsensectr": 0,
        "ga:adsenseecpm": 0,
        "ga:adsenserevenue": 0,
        "ga:adsenseviewableimpressionpercent": 0,
        "ga:contentgroup1": "some string",
        "ga:contentgroup2": "some string",
        "ga:date": 20190704,
        "ga:hostname": "some string",
        "ga:hour": 12,
        "ga:keyword": "some string",
        "ga:pagepath": "some string",
        "ga:pagetitle": "some string",
        "ga:pageviews": 1,
        "ga:sessions": 1,
        "ga:source": "some string",
        "host": "some string",
        "adsenseattached": 1,
        "eventtime": "2019-07-04T12:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "1251616",
        "press": "8",
        "reg_date": "2019-05-22T14:06:25.000Z",  #and .. this line also
        "scenario_id": 5072,
        "scheduletype": "1",
    ....
    ....
```

6. I think that reg_date column is perfectly normal.
7. But when I run glue crawler and preview with athena, it turns weird.

```sql
#in athena
SELECT "id","reg_date","scenario_reg_date" FROM "catalog-name"."table_name" limit 10
```

result is

```
idx|id     |reg_date                 |scenario_reg_date
1  |1251616|+51357-12-22 18:56:40.000|2019-05-15 15:04:24
2  |1361993|+51390-05-01 13:36:40.000|2019-05-15 15:04:24
3  |1461362|+51417-09-19 00:53:20.000|2019-05-15 15:04:24
4  |1461362|+51417-09-19 00:53:20.000|2019-05-15 15:04:24
5  |1461362|+51417-09-19 00:53:20.000|2019-05-15 15:04:24
```

8. 'reg_date' column turns totaly weird!
9. The glue crawler is setted all basic, only set iam, datacatalog name, s3 source and they are basic setting category

The type of things is next:

```py
type(result_df['reg_date'][0])
#pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

type(result_df['scenario_reg_date'][0])
#str
```

**I tried the next things.**

1. dataframe.to_parquet(engine='pyarrow')
   it saves timestamp to bigint type. so glue crawler recognize it bigint type too. and athena query also shows it bigint type.
2. dataframe['reg_date'] = dataframe['reg_date'].apply(lambda x : x.to_pydatetime().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
   in this case, s3 console shows it normal but glue crawler recognized it 'string' type... and athena also.

I think parquet format has some secret to save its schema.

**I expect...**

Glue crawler parse datetime data to normal timetick.
not **+51357-12-22 18:56:40.000**, just **2019-05-22 14:06:25.000** like **scenario_reg_date** column.

And I want to know why this problem is occurring.

I drilled into it for over 5 hours, and it ruined my whole day.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Athena requires the Java TIMESTAMP format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.fffffffff`. You need to adjust your value to match this format. 
[Source here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/query-table-athena-timestamp-empty/)

Notice that Glue crawlers often fail to detect timestamp columns and classify them as strings (like your `scenario_reg_date`). So if you wish to use date functionality later on those columns, you'll to take the table's DDL > manually convert data types > drop & recreate the table.

Comment: thank you. i solved it with using fastparquet's int96 timestamp option. i think maybe it preserves 1e-9 timestamp precision. (and also i think it makes don't confuse with bigint)